# Getting started with Jupyter in the cloud

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cloud

So far I've only used Jupyter on my local machine, which is way too slow. I'm completely new to using cloud services for Jupyter, or using cloud services at all for that matter. I know there are a million tutorials out there, but this is my problem: How to choose the right service from all those options (Amazon? Google? Cheaper options?)? What's the 'right way' to get started?

What I need:

- I want a service where I can start up a Jupyter notebook in my browser as simply as possible. (I know next to nothing about setting up servers etc., and have very limited time to learn that if needed)
- I currently have an old MacBook from 2014. The server should be at least 10x faster. (Which options do I need to pick?)
- I want to do machine learning, so GPUs would be good.
- My budget is about $50 per month, less would be great; a free tryout would be great too.
- As I am completely new, I also need to know what pitfalls to look out for. (E.g.: Stop the machine to stop increasing the costs?)

If you could help me, or point me to a good tutorial or even a book, I'd be forever grateful.
(Sorry for the basic question. Of course I googled tutorials myself before posting this question, but as indicated above, I'm overwhelmed by the options - that's why I posted this question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS based tutorial:
https://aws.amazon.com/de/getting-started/hands-on/get-started-dlami/

GPU, CPU and pricing informations are gathered here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/pricing.html

You can set up a budget for cost limitation:
https://aws.amazon.com/de/getting-started/hands-on/control-your-costs-free-tier-budgets/

Comment: Cool, thanks so much! :) Can you add a few words about why you chose AWS?

Comment: I do only know the AWS services. Perhaps MS Azure has similar services, but I don't know ;)